# Array not returning default value set over 1,000,000 when using jquery fancy comma script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, forms

I have the jquery fancy comma script added within my site for use on my form.

1 of the form input fields is a price option where the user enters a specific price related to their needs, Upon doing so they do not need to enter the commas between the price so for example if they type (900000)  it will automatically display as (900,000) and this starts from (1,000).

I have a PHP array script running that will return a default value set for within a range that they can input... This is below.

```
 $data = array(
    array(
        'min' => 0,000,
        'max' => 100,000,
        'value' => 125
    ),
    array(
        'min' => 101,000,
        'max' => 200,000,
        'value' => 195
    ),
    array(
        'min' => 201,000,
        'max' => 300,000,
        'value' => 225
    ),
    array(
        'min' => 301,000,
        'max' => 400,000,
        'value' => 275
    ),
    array(
        'min' => 401,000,
        'max' => 500,000,
        'value' => 325
    ),
    array(
        'min' => 501,000,
        'max' => 600,000,
        'value' => 375
    ),
    array(
        'min' => 601,000,
        'max' => 700,000,
        'value' => 425
    ),
    array(
        'min' => 701,000,
        'max' => 800,000,
        'value' => 475
    ),
    array(
        'min' => 801,000,
        'max' => 900,000,
        'value' => 525
    ),
    array(
        'min' => 901,000,
        'max' => 999,999,
        'value' => 625
    ),
    array(
        'min' => 1,000,000,
        'max' => 3,000,000,
        'value' => 725
    ),
    array(
        'min' => 3,000,001,
        'max' => 6,000,000,
        'value' => 800
    ),
    array(
        'min' => 6,000,001,
        'max' => 600,000,000,
        'value' => 925
    )
);

function getAdjustedPrice($price, &$table) {
    $priceData = current(array_filter($table, function($value) use(&$price) {
        return $value['min'] <= $price && $value['max'] >= $price;
    }));
    return $priceData['value'];
}

$input = intval($_SESSION["userinput"]);
printf("", 
       $input, 
       getAdjustedPrice($input, $data));
```

The problem i have is as soon as the price exceeds 999,999 and you enter 1,000,000 and above so there are two commas in the input, The array fails to display the default price set for that range.

Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated. Maybe someone has a better way of setting the default value for each range, Maybe a jquery or javascript based option?

Im still learning the very basics so please do forgive my ignorance or idiotic approach to things!

---- UPDATE (ADDING THE CODE USED TO APPLY COMMAS)

```
--------------------------  First Section


    function addCommas(val) {
    val = val.replace(/,/g, "");
    var regEx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (regEx.test(val)) {
        val = val.replace(regEx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return val;
    };;


    --------------------------- Second section


        // Fancy commas
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            var newValue = addCommas($(this).val());
            $(this).val(addCommas(newValue));
            if (PropValueS.val().indexOf('\u00A3') == -1) {
                PropValueS.val('\u00A3' + PropValueS.val());
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: If you run `var_export($data);` you'll see that your script does not trigger a syntax error by pure chance. Numbers in most programming languages just don't have commas: you need to use **strings**.

Comment: Alvaro what would you recommend doing?  Running them as:  100000 - 200000 as appose to 100,000 - 200,000 ? thanks for taking time to advise, i am still learning so sometimes it takes me a little longer than most to realize the obvious. Thanks

Comment: If you have prices you probably need to do calculations. Use real numbers for that. An exaggerated example: what code looks easier to maintain, `$total = 29.25 * 1.15;` or `$total = apply_taxes('twenty-nine dollars ninety-nine cents', '15 percent');`?

Comment: The reason i have the prices like that is because the form user inputs the value of their property (Home they live in) and our script will return the default value set within the range they enter the value. As you can see everything up to 999,999 works fine so if the user enters 325,000 it would return £275 and that's because we have £275 value set for the 301,000 - 400,000 range. I dont need it to do any calculations or taxes to be applied its just the issue i have when the input value exceeds 999,999 and two commas are involved and becomes (1,000,000 and so on...)

Comment: i did not know if there was an alternative method like jquery or java or maybe another php way that will return the default value for the range that is set.. So if the form user is to enter 220,000 it would return the value set for the range (100,000 => 200,000) and so on.. up to 6,000,000

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with the commas since googling jquery fancy comma script didn't yield any results.

What I think is happening is that your data isn't being interpreted the way you think it is. I am not well versed in PHP but

```
'min' => 3,000,001
```

Most likely adds three entries to the array, `min => 3`, `000`, and `001`.

Also, as a suggestion, I would handle the logic of your data in the following way:

```
var inputValue = 220000; // Change to the value extracted from the input form
var value = 0;

if(inputValue >= 0 && inputValue < 100000) {
    value = 125;
}
else if(inputValue >= 100000 && inputValue < 200000) {
    value = 195;
}
else if(inputValue >= 200000 && inputValue < 300000) {
    value = 225;
}
...
```

Comment: Would i use inputValue as the variable in the above code? so my value would be set to value="inputValue"  and how would i be able to echo the default value set back to the user would it be a simple case of ( echo "$value" )  Thanks for taking time out to assist its much appreciated

Comment: amalgam54 i have added the code for the comma script above in my original post.  Thanks

Comment: What I don't understand is why your numerical values have commas in the PHP script. If a client is inputting data with commas, you can remove them, do the calculations required, and add them back at the end. As I suggested before, if you want your PHP code to work, you need to map strings to integers, so 'min' => 3000001, not 'min' => 3,000,001